# Vue3 - API Composition : Custom v-model prop

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

In Vue2, the v-model bind to the prop `value`, but it's possible [to define a other prop](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html#Customizing-Component-v-model) :

```js
Vue.component('base-checkbox', {
  model: {
    prop: 'checked',
    event: 'change'
  },
  props: {
    checked: Boolean
  },
  template: `
    <input
      type="checkbox"
      v-bind:checked="checked"
      v-on:change="$emit('change', $event.target.checked)"
    >
  `
})
```

I want do the same in Vue 3 with API Composition.

How do you define a custom prop to v-model in Vue 3 with the API Composition?

Example :

```html
<script setup lang="ts">

defineProps({
    msg: {
        type: String,
    }
});

defineEmits(['update:msg'])

defineModel('msg', 'update:msg'); 

</script>

<template>
    <div>
        {{ msg }}
    </div>
    <button @click="$emit('update:msg', 'Clicked!')">Switch</button>
</template>
```

Of course `defineModel` don't exist, but I must not be far from the truth.

Comment: You just dont need that "defineModel" line, but your code seems fine

Comment: if a component has a prop `myProp` and emits an event `update:myProp`, you can do `v-model:myProp=...` in Vue 3, same as `.sync` in vue 2

Comment: @LoïcMonard, the code work to `<MyComponent v-model:msg="foo"/>`, but I want just `<MyComponent v-model="foo"/>`  like in Vue 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Vue 3 the model option are removed and replaced with an argument on `v-model`

So if you want to change the `v-model` prop you can by changing the `defineProps` and `defineEmits` to use another name than `modelValue`.

However you cannot implicitly use `v-model` without adding the new custom prop name after the `v-model`.

You have to specify it like this : `v-model:myCustomPropName`.

```html
<template>
  <input :value="myCustomPropName" @input="$emit('update:myCustomPropName', $event.target.value)" />
</template>

<script setup>
import { defineProps, defineEmits } from "vue";

defineProps(["myCustomPropName"]);
defineEmits(["update:myCustomPropName"]);
</script>
```

Usage:

```html
<MyCustomInput v-model:myCustomPropName="msg" />
```

Vue 3 props Doc : https://vuejs.org/guide/components/v-model.html

See the changes from Vue 2 to Vue 3 : https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/v-model.html

Answer (score 3):

As of 3.3.0-alpha.9 (2023-04-08), there is defineModels. You don't need to define any emits or props, I believe just let {msg} = defineModels(['msg']). Then you can do msg.value = .... If you only have one modelValue, you don't have to pass any arguments at all. I'm not even sure if it's defineModel or defineModels, this video and the update tracker conflicts. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6xhF9HCTf9s

https://github.com/vuejs/core/blob/main/CHANGELOG

Edit:

An example would be:

```js
const model = defineModel()
model.value = model.value + 1
```

Right now to do the same you would have to do:

```js
const props = defineProps(['modelValue'])
const emit = defineEmits(['update:modelValue'])
emit('update:modelValue', props.modelValue + 1)
```

Comment: The functionality is in experimental status. When it will be released, I will accept your answer. Can you add a example?

Comment: @vernou I don't know when it will be released, I think I heard someone mention May, but I don't know really. An example would be `const model = defineModel()` `model.value = model.value + 1`. Right now to do the same you would do `const props = defineProps(['modelValue'])` `const emit = defineEmits(['update:modelValue'])` `emit('update:modelValue', props.modelValue + 1)`. Sorry for bad formatting, it won't let me do code blocks for some reason.

Comment: can you add the example in the answer?